# nextElementSibling is null

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to make testimonials module with vanilla JS and I have a problem when I using a "for" cycle with collection - the console writes **testimonials[i].nextElementSibling is null**. There is no problem when I manually set the index of collection's element - it works.

```
<section class="testimonials-wrap">     
            <h2>testimonials</h2>
            <div>
                <p class="active">Mauris quis nulla ut dui luctus euismod ac sit amet diam. Nulla ullamcorper tortor nec.</p>
                <p>Vivamus aliquet massa nec odio sagittis, eget faucibus metus malesuada. Nam sed neque pellentesque, cursus.</p>
                <p>Sed bibendum nec ligula sit amet accumsan. Sed neque est, commodo sed tortor in, tincidunt.</p>
            </div>
        <ul>
            <li class="next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></li>
            <li class="prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></li>
        </ul>
</section>

function goToTheNextTest(){
    var testimonials = document.getElementsByClassName("testimonials-wrap")[0].getElementsByTagName("div")[0].getElementsByTagName("p");
    for(var i = 0; i < testimonials.length; i++){
        if(testimonials[i].className === "active"){
            testimonials[i].className = "";
            //testimonials[i].nextElementSibling.className = "active";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check what is coming in `testimonials[i]` ?

Comment: No I did not. How is better to do it ?

Comment: `var testimonials = document.querySelectorAll(".testimonials-wrap > div > p");`

Comment: As I understand the cycle here is not usable because the code executes after event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the for loop in this way.

```
for(var i = 0; i < testimonials.length-1; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're trying to get the next element in your loop, but there are no more elements available so:

```
if (i !== testimonials.length -1) {
        testimonials[i].nextElementSibling.className = "active";
}
```

Basically, only get the *next element sibling* if it's not the last iteration; so if you have 3 elements, don't attempt to get 4.

tesimonials.length is 3, so we subtract 1